# Cloud machine for Windows .NET app

Tags: hosting, amazon-ec2, web-hosting, shared-hosting, vps

I am currently running a new .NET application on an Amazon instance. I really like it, as it comes with Windows 2k8, IIS7 and SQL server pre-installed. However, it's costing a bit, at about $90/month for a small instance, which is catagorized as:

"Small Instance (Default) 1.7 GB of memory, 1 EC2 Compute Unit (1 virtual core with 1 EC2 Compute Unit), 160 GB of local instance storage, 32-bit platform"

Is there a cheaper alternative (VPS??) to the above Amazon EC2 service? I would prefer a service people have had experience/success with, not necessarily the dirt cheapest on the market.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this won't get deleted for not being a programming question: BUT - I've actually done quite well with GoDaddy's Server 2003 instances, which are much less than 90/mo.  They don't handle massive load, but they have been very stable for me.

Comment: Hey, programs run on servers, no ;-)?

Comment: Does GoDaddy give full box access (RDP) as opposed to just an annoying panel interface?

Comment: Yes, with one restriction that I was able to deal with - you can't apply windows updates.  Also, make sure you select the 'no control panel' option; they have special support reps for their dedicated servers.